# Pattern matching in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a data in a column like below

```
'ABC This is sample' 
'This is ABC sample'
'This is sample ABC'
```

How can I search for records containing the word 'ABC' and similarly few more words 'XYZ', so on?

I used **rlike '( ABC | XYZ | DEF )'** but this gives me only row 2 'This is ABC sample' (note the white spaces). Is there any way where I can get all 3 records? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rlike '(^| )(ABC|XYZ|DEF)($| )'
```